# Image/Files not Being Posted Django

Tags: python, django, image

I have been trying to Post Images in Django and I don't know why they are not being posted. I use **image = form.cleaned_data.get("image")** and It is not being save. whenever I save the image won't get saved but the text or the content gets saved, now I'm perplexed. Please Help Me...

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "post_img", null = True, blank = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} // {self.author}"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title", "content", "image"]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    posts=Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
    context ={
        "posts":posts
    }
    return render(request, "index.html",context)


def post_view(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
        content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
        image = form.cleaned_data.get("image")
        activeUser = request.user
        post = Post.objects.create(title = title, content = content, image = image, author = activeUser)
        post.save()
        return redirect("posts:home")
    else:
        form = PostForm()


    return render(request, "post.html", {"form": form})
```

post.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<form method = "POST" action = ".">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{form|crispy }}
  </div>
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Done</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I have selected the Picture and posted but still, my image won't get saved in the database
[[image: ][1]]

Comment: Hello @Aakash Thapa try to print `form.cleaned_data.get("image")` check whether it's getting file or not and if it's getting file than provide your media url and media root configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form tag you have to add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** and you have to include **{{form.media}}** in the template if you want to post **any type of file** to Django.

```
<form method = "POST" action = "." enctype="multipart/form-data">

 {% csrf_token %}
 
 {{form.media}}
 
 <div class="form-group">

   {{form|crispy }}

 </div>

 <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Done</button>

</form>
```